# Maven-Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 56473600; received: 6843

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to use the mvn depenedency get to download the tar file from the repo. Here is the command:

```
mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=com.sample -DartifactId=sample-project -Dversion=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dtransitive=false -Dpackaging=tar
```

This gives me the below error:

```
[ERROR] : Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 56473600; received: 6843
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

The same command works on windows.

If I change the command to download the jar, it works:

```
mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=com.sample -DartifactId=sample-project -Dversion=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dtransitive=false -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use ? And which version of maven-dependency-plugin do you use?